# Problem in specifying the network in cloud dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, vpc

I didn't configure the project and I get this error whenever I run my job '*The network default doesn't have rules that open TCP ports 1-65535 for internal connection with other VMs. Only rules with a target tag 'dataflow' or empty target tags set apply. If you don't specify such a rule, any pipeline with more than one worker that shuffles data will hang. Causes: No firewall rules associated with your network.*'

```
google_cloud_options = p_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
google_cloud_options.region = 'europe-west1'
google_cloud_options.project = 'my-project'
google_cloud_options.job_name = 'rim'
google_cloud_options.staging_location = 'gs://my-bucket/binaries'
google_cloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://my-bucket/temp'
p_options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'
p_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
p_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
p_options.view_as(WorkerOptions).subnetwork = 'regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/test'
p = beam.Pipeline(options=p_options)
```

I tried to specify --network 'test' in the command line since it is not the default configuration 
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your default firewall rules were modified and dataflow detected this and prevented your job from launching. Could you verify your firewall rules were not modified in your project?. Please take a look at the [documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/routes-firewall). You will also find a command here to restore the firewall rules:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create [FIREWALL_RULE_NAME] \
    --network [NETWORK] \
    --action allow \
    --direction ingress \
    --target-tags dataflow \
    --source-tags dataflow \
    --priority 0 \
    --rules tcp:1-65535
```

Pick a name for the firewall, and provide a network name. Then pass in the network name with --network when you launch the dataflow job. If you have a network named 'default' dataflow will try to use that automatically, so you won't need to pass in --network. If you've deleted that network you may wish to recreate it.

Answer (score 4):

As of now, till apache beam version 2.19.0. There is no provision from dataflow  to set network tag for its VM.
Instead while creating firewall rule, we should add a tag for dataflow.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create FIREWALL_RULE_NAME \
    --network NETWORK \
    --action allow \
    --direction DIRECTION \
    --target-tags dataflow \
    --source-tags dataflow \
    --priority 0 \
    --rules tcp:12345-12346
```

See this link for more details
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/routes-firewall